# Python-Javascript Hash library to make sure that a JSON object did not get corrupted in transit

Tags: javascript, python, hash, corruption, validation

Is there a library available that can help make sure that JSON objects being sent back and forth between a server running Python and a Javascript client have not been corrupted?

I'm thinking it would probably work by creating a hash of the object to be sent a long with the object. Then the receiver of the object could re-hash the object ans make sure that it matches the hash that it received.

Is this something that I should even be concerned about, or is this something that browsers and clients normally have taken care of behind the scenes anyway?

Thanks!

Comment: how do you know the hash wasn't corrupted if it's sent over with the JSON string?

Comment: The probability of that is extremely low

Comment: If the hash or the object was corrupted, then the comparison would fail and the data would be rejected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP has built-in error checking, and so do most link layer network protocols. So there's both per-link and end-to-end checks taking place. The only thing this doesn't protect against is intentional modification of the data, e.g. by a firewall, proxy, or network hacker. However, they can modify the hash as well as the JSON, so adding a hash doesn't protect against them. If you need real, secure protection you need to use cryptography, e.g. SSL.

Comment: I wasn't too concerned about security. Mainly if a bit got flipped somewhere along the way...